# Insert bulk data in background in .Net Core

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, background-service

I'm using .Net Core 3.1 and I want to insert bulk data in the background, so I don't need my http request waiting for it "like fire and forget"

So I tried the following code

```cs
public object myFunction(){
    Task.Factor.StartNew(() => {
        _context.BulkInsertAsync(logs);
    });

    return data;
}
```

But nothing is happend, no data saved in database
is after my data returned my _context and logs will be null, so the process is filed?
or there is any another method to insert my data and don't wait for it

Note: the background task working if I replace insertion statment with sending mail or any other thing

**Solved**:

Thanks @Peter , I solved it using

```
Task.Run(async () => await _context.BulkInsertAsync(logs));
```

Comment: The `StartNew` will return with a Task, which is not awaited, so you just spawn a new job and immediately return. Please share more details because we don't know the life-cycle of the context, we don't know how what data is and how is it populated.

Comment: _context is used by constructor DI, so I use it before 'Task' to get & save data to database then I insert the bulk logs and return data, so I need the returned data asap and logs to continue inserting after request is done and data is returned

Comment: Okey, but what is the lifecycle of the `_context`. Is it registered as singleton or as transient or xyz? Is there anyone else how is using that context? Are aware of that fact the DbContext is not thread-safe, so each thread should use its own instance? But first and foremost why do you want to separate insert data and log insert? Shouldn't they be in the same transaction? Or is it enough to log them in a best effort way?

Comment: in my startup I registerd dbContext as ServiceLifetime.Transient, I tried to create new _context in the thread using ServiceProvider but it didn't work, and I need to separate insert data and log insert as my bulk log insertion takes around 2~3 seconds, and it is a redundant that user wait for the logs to be inserted

Comment: Have you tried `Task.Run(async () => await _context.BulkInsertAsync(logs));` `StartNew` does not have an overload, which accepts `Func<Task>`

Comment: Yeah, it is working thank you so much, the key was I had to mention async() then await the _context.BulkInsertAsync

Comment: I left an answer with the solution for future readers. I highly encourage you to read the mentioned blogpost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` or `TaskFactory.StartNew` cannot accept async delegates (`Func<Task>`), so you should use `Task.Run` instead which is indeed has an [overload with Func < Task >](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__). You would have to use `await await` or `Unwrap` against `StartNew` to get the same behaviour as with `Run`. Please read [Stephen Toub's excellent blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

```
public object myFunction(){
    Task.Run(async () => await _context.BulkInsertAsync(logs));
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implement it. This assumes the response is not important.

```
public NotImportantResult ProcessBulkData()
{
    myFunctionAsync();
    return new NotImportantResult() 
}  

private static async void myFunctionAsync()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new MyBulkProccessor.BulkInsertAsync(logs));
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `Task.Factory.StartNew` inside the `BulkInsertAsync`? `InternalBeginBulkProcess` shouldn't be async?

Comment: @Peter Csala - I am removing that part for confusion. I took it from a class I used that support both asynchronous and non-asynchronous operations. The internal part was used by both. That probally added confusion for this question.

Comment: Are you sure about `async void`?